# Remove custom quantity field when product out of stock on WooCommerce archives

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, product-quantity

I am trying to remove the quantity selector box from shop, category and product pages when the item is out of stock. Is there an easy way to not show the quantity selector box using code?

I am using the code below to show the quantity selector box.

```
 /**
   * Add quantity field on the archive page.
  */
 function custom_quantity_field_archive() {

$product = wc_get_product( get_the_ID() );

if ( ! $product->is_sold_individually() && 'variable' != $product- 
>product_type && $product->is_purchasable() ) {
    woocommerce_quantity_input( array( 'min_value' => 1, 'max_value' => 
$product->backorders_allowed() ? '' : $product->get_stock_quantity() ) );
}

}
   add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 
   'custom_quantity_field_archive', 0, 9 );


/**
* Add requires JavaScript.
 */
 function custom_add_to_cart_quantity_handler() {

wc_enqueue_js( '
    jQuery( ".post-type-archive-product" ).on( "click", ".quantity input", 
 function() {
        return false;
    });
    jQuery( ".post-type-archive-product" ).on( "change input", ".quantity 
.qty", function() {
        var add_to_cart_button = jQuery( this ).parents( ".product" ).find( 
  ".add_to_cart_button" );

        // For AJAX add-to-cart actions
        add_to_cart_button.data( "quantity", jQuery( this ).val() );

        // For non-AJAX add-to-cart actions
        add_to_cart_button.attr( "href", "?add-to-cart=" + 
  add_to_cart_button.attr( "data-product_id" ) + "&quantity=" + jQuery( this 
  ).val() );
    });
' );

 }
  add_action( 'init', 'custom_add_to_cart_quantity_handler' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the WooCommerce Template.
Open a woocommerce folder inside your theme folder and then
single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php

Copy-paste the code from woocommerce plugin/templates/single-template/add-to-cart/simple.php

on line no 46 you will see:

```
woocommerce_quantity_input( array(
  'min_value'   => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_min', $product->get_min_purchase_quantity(), $product ),
  'max_value'   => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_max', $product->get_max_purchase_quantity(), $product ),
  'input_value' => isset( $_POST['quantity'] ) ? wc_stock_amount( $_POST['quantity'] ) : $product->get_min_purchase_quantity(),
) );
```

You can add custom if statement before calling the `woocommerce_quantity_input` function:

```
if($product->get_stock_quantity() > 0) {
  // woocommerce_quantity_input calling here...
}
```

**NOTE** [Template structure & Overriding templates via a theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)

Comment: ok I wrapped your code around the woo code in the simple.php file but the quantity input box still appears?

Comment: Hey James Donald, Make sure to add the exact template path in your theme file. Otherwise template overriding won't work.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for additional code as WooCommerce does this automatically. On the Inventory tab when you're editing the product, tick "Manage Stock" and then select "Allow back-orders?" and set it to "Do not allow".

Comment: strangely i checked settings on a simple product and the settings are specified as Enable manage stock and Do not allow back orders ticked? Ok so to clarify I just checked the actual product page and yes there are no add to cart or quantity selectors present - My quantity selector box is appearing on the shop page and category + product pages.

Comment: Ah, now that's telling... WC doesn't add the quantity selector to the shop or category loops by default, so it must be being added by your theme. I suggest you reach out to your theme developer.

Answer (score 0):

For your archives pages quantity field, you will need to make some change in your code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'custom_quantity_field_archive', 0, 9 )
function custom_quantity_field_archive() {
    global $product;

    if ( ! $product->is_sold_individually() && ! $product->is_type('variable') 
    && $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() ) {
        woocommerce_quantity_input( array( 
            'min_value' => 1, 
            'max_value' => $product->backorders_allowed() ? '' : $product->get_stock_quantity() 
        ) );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should work.

Comment: @JamesDonald This is your based code and it works without any error… I have just added  `&& $product->is_in_stock()` to the if statement and replaced little things. May be you haven't removed your code before adding this one… But this doesn't make any error…